# why is find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME) not working in selenium, python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm working on a project where I scrape stories from reddit, and I've run into a problem. For each subreddit, the button you click to take you to the post includes the HTML:

```
<a class="absolute inset-0" slot="full-post-link" href="*the link*" target="_self">
```

The specific code I've tried to test this with is:

```
<a class="absolute inset-0" slot="full-post-link" href="/r/ProRevenge/comments/cvb3b6/coworker_tried_to_get_me_fired_over_breast/" target="_self">
  <faceplate-screen-reader-content>
    #shadow-root (open)
      <!---->
      <slot>
        <#text>
      </slot>
    Coworker tried to get me fired over breast implants, so I pulled a reverse uno card.
  </faceplate-screen-reader-content>
</a>
```

I want to retrieve this link and go to it, and have tried:

```
links = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'absolute inset-0')
```

But when this runs I'm just given an empty array.

For clarification, I did try finding and clicking the button using `By.XPATH`, which worked just fine. The only thing is I know using XPATHs is really bad practice, and I'd rather find the button through `By.CLASS_NAME`. The following code gave me what I need:

```
storyBtn = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/shreddit-app/dsa-transparency-modal-provider/div/div[1]/div[2]/main/div[2]/article[1]/shreddit-post/a[1]')
storyBtn.click()
url = str(driver.current_url)
```

The link I'm using is: https://www.reddit.com/r/ProRevenge/top/?t=all
Does anyone know what's up?

Comment: Can u provide link of page where u have problem? So, I can take look where is the problem and can give clear answer. Also, can u provide full version of <a>tag

Comment: @MuhammedSamedÖzmen I just edited the post :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<a class="absolute inset-0" slot="full-post-link" href="*the link*" target="_self">
```

You can see the value of class attribute includes space, it mean it has multiple values.
In this case it has two values, `absolute` and `inset-0`, not `absolute inset-0`.

`By.CLASS_NAME` accepts only single class name.
`By.CSS_SELECTOR` accepts even multiple classes.

You can try

```py
links = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.absolute.inset-0')
```

Comment: I had no idea about this- thank you!